# How social_stream register new user works (using devise gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, registration, social-stream

I'm trying social_stream gem (https://github.com/ging/social_stream). It uses devise gem for user registration. When I register a new user on social_stream, it creates new records in several tables. I checked the code in social stream, the registration method is not overrided. So I'm totally lost. I can't find how new records are inserted in the other tables except user table. There are several new records inserted into the following tables: channels, actors, profile, activity_objects, relations, permissions. But I can't find the connection between users to these tables.

Can anyone help me to point out how social stream works when new user register?

Thank you

Comment: inside social_stream's gemspec's [file](https://github.com/ging/social_stream/blob/master/social_stream.gemspec) you'll see it relies on `social_stream-base` which has a gemspec [file](https://github.com/ging/social_stream/blob/master/base/social_stream-base.gemspec) on its own that says it uses devise.

Answer (score 0):

You can see on User model ( https://github.com/ging/social_stream/blob/master/base/app/models/user.rb#L8 ) there are several has_many association.

In the find_or_create_for_facebook_oauth method there are a User and Authentication method create.

https://github.com/ging/social_stream/blob/master/base/app/models/user.rb#L118

Comment: What I mean is not only authentication records. There are new records created in several other tables, like channels, actors, profile, activity_objects, relations, permissions, etc. I don't see the dependency from user to those tables.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [database schema](https://github.com/ging/social_stream/wiki/Social-Stream-Base-database-schema) to get a glimpse of the architecture (and complexity) of social stream.

I may be wrong, but as social stream is based on device, it's devise that handles the user registration (check devise/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb). You might want to move that into your app [to override](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines) this behavior.

Given the overall complexity of social stream, think twice before building your project on top of it.

---

Pros for using it:

- You have a deep knowledge of rails and engines, so you can customise it easily
- You can understand the code of others, and complex models easily (so you will actually understand what's going on under the covers)
- Or you just want to prototype and then throw your project away

Cons:

- You need just a few social stream features (eg, just user registration and adding friends)
- You are on a long term project
- You don't have much rails experience

Comment: so have you used it before? what if i do have good knowledge of rails and engines.. will it actually scale? or will i have to necessarily throw it away once my project hits a certain point?